# Google Cloud Endpoints not working with Eclipse WTP

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I created a new WTP project in Eclipse that uses `App Engine` based on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform). I also use `Google Clound Endpoints`. The issue is that I can't access my API anymore.

`http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis` returns

```
{
  "kind" : "discovery#directoryList",
  "discoveryVersion" : "v1"
}
```

I also tried to generate the javascript client library but I get an error `Not an app engine project`. I managed to generate the javascript library with the command line.

Anybody managed to use the new GPE with Endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, we don't have endpoints working with WTP-style projects as yet (the released version is a preview). We're working on this right now.